# MvxAutoCompleteTextView dropdown re-opens on every keypress

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, autocompletetextview

I have a problem whereby upon every keypress from the user, the AutoCompleteTextView quickly hides and re-appears again (with an updated set of values).

Please suggest where my problem could be and whether you see any other problems with the below code.

Binding in the View:

```
bindingSet
   .Bind(emailAutoCompleteTextView)
   .For(t => t.Text)
   .To(vm => vm.Email);

bindingSet
    .Bind(emailAutoCompleteTextView)
    .For(t => t.PartialText)
    .To(vm => vm.CurrentEmailEntry);

bindingSet
    .Bind(emailAutoCompleteTextView)
    .For(t => t.ItemsSource)
    .To(vm => vm.CurrentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions);
```

AXML Layout:

```
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/EmailAutoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/PaddingBetweenUserInputFields"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

View Model Code:

```
private string _currentEmailEntry;

public string CurrentEmailEntry
{
    get
    {
        return _currentEmailEntry;
    }
    set
    {
        _currentEmailEntry = value;

        if (value == string.Empty)
        {
            _currentEmailEntry = null;
        }

        CurrentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions = _emailAutoCompleteList
            .Where(email => email.StartsWith(_currentEmailEntry, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToArray();

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentEmailEntry));
    }
}        

private static readonly string[] _emailAutoCompleteList = {"Gordon", "Gordy", "Go", "Freeman", "Is", "Alive"};

private IList<string> _currentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions = _emailAutoCompleteList.ToList();

public IList<string> CurrentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions
{
    get { return _currentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions; }
    set
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(_currentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions, value))
            return;

        _currentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentEmailAutoCompleteSuggestions));
    }
}
```

I use MvvmCross 4.0 (upgrade is not an option).

NB: I tried using an `ObservableCollection` instead of an `IList` and remove/add items to it (not re-assign the collection itself) but after that the setter for `CurrentEmailEntry` stopped receiving values after the user typed the first character into the text view. The code inside `MvxFilteringAdapter` seems to be stuck waiting on a reset event.

Answer (score 2):

Since no one answered either here or on the MvvmCross Xamarin Slack channel I eventually discovered the solution myself.

It was the re-creation of the list bound to the `ItemsSource` that led to the strange behaviour in question.

The `ObservableCollection` with `Clear()/Add()` instead of re-creating was indeed the way to go. The stuck behaviour (waiting on the reset event) described in the last question paragraph was caused by the absence of proper thread dispatching (my application is multi-threaded).

As soon as I wrapped my observable collection with a proxy collection that always raised the `CollectionChanged` event **on the UI thread**, the problem disappeared.

Leaving this here for the benefit of future generations.